# Spring JPA - Implement unique constraints in code - Tx isolation level

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I need to implement unique constrain validation using spring data jpa, and i know it can be done with jpa annotations but i need to do it manually.

I have a class (entity) User like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String email;

    private Date createdAt;

}
```

When i create a new User i have to validate that no other user with identical username or password exists. 
I know i need to do something like this (more or less):

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public List<User> findByUsernameOrEmail(String username, String email);

}

public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public User create(User user) {

        List<User> users = this.userRepository.findByUsernameOrEmail(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail());

        if (users.size() > 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("No repeated username or email allowed");

        User newUser = this.userRepository.save(user);

        return newUser;

    }

}
```

My question is: what type of transaction isolation level should i use ? 
Is it REPETEABLE_READ enough ? I need to avoid duplicated users

Comment: I think you need full table lock. With `REPETEABLE_READ` other transaction can still insert new `User` with same username and password after call to `findByUsernameOrEmail` but before `userRepository.save`.

Comment: @tsolakp did you mean SERIALIZABLE then ? Are there other options ?

Comment: I think SERIALIZABLE is the only option you have.

Comment: Why don't you create a unique constraint on the database?

Comment: why are you making it transactional, which operation you want to rollback in case of failure?

Comment: Simon Martinelli i'm not allowed to touch the db. 
@MohitSharma i don't understand. what would be the other option ?

Comment: Your JPA implementation classes will be handling the transactions, you don't need to do this, just write the method without the transaction, if you are performing any operation after save and that should maintain the ACID properties then only you need transactional.